# Adding Layers to Heron Template

Tags: geoext, openlayers-2, heron-mapping-client

I've got this piece of code below that is supposed to display two base layers but now the OSM_LAYER disables(becomes blurry and inactive in the layer tree) the WORLD_LAYER, I'm not sure what the problem is. If it fits, I'd welcome the advice on how to change the OSM_LAYER to be in the format of WORLD_LAYER.

```
Heron.options.map.layers = [

 new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(),

new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "World image",
        'http://www2.demis.nl/wms/wms.ashx?WMS=BlueMarble',
        {layers: "Earth Image", format: 'image/png'},
        {singleTile: true,
        isBaseLayer: true, 
        visibility: false, 
        noLegend: true}
)]
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition you can only have one base layer (i.e the bottom layer) enabled at any one time.  You can define multiple layers to act as base layers, but only **one** can be **THE** base layer at any point in time.

To identify the OSM layer as a potential base layer use:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
  "isBaseLayer":true
),
```

When you add multiple base layers to a map, the first listed becomes the default base layer.